# Query working in Teradata but not in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

If I execute the following code I am able to get desired output; But in Oracle is am facing error :

```
SELECT NAME
  FROM STUD
 WHERE ID IN (
                 SEL DISTINCT  TAB1.ID  
                FROM (
                              SEL A.ID
                                , B.SALARY
                             FROM Fr   A
                       INNER JOIN PACK B ON A.ID = B.ID
                     ) AS TAB1
          INNER JOIN (
                              SEL A.FRIEND_ID
                                , B.SALARY
                             FROM Fr    A
                       INNER JOIN PACK  B ON A.FRIEND_ID = B.ID
                     ) AS TAB2
                  ON TAB2.SALARY > TAB1.SALARY
      )
    ;
```

Facing the below error in oracle :
    ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis

Answer (score 1):

You have two errors: `SEL` instead of `SELECT` and the usage of table aliases with `AS` keyword, which is not supported by Oracle

```
SELECT NAME
  FROM STUD
 WHERE ID IN (SELECT DISTINCT  TAB1.ID  FROM
(SELECT A.ID , B.SALARY
FROM
Fr   A
INNER JOIN
PACK B
ON
A.ID = B.ID)  TAB1
INNER JOIN
(SELECT A.FRIEND_ID , B.SALARY
FROM
Fr  A
INNER JOIN
PACK  B
ON
A.FRIEND_ID = B.ID
)  TAB2
ON
TAB2.SALARY > TAB1.SALARY
)
```

Besides this, I think you don't need the `DISTINCT` in the inner query, given that you only use it in an `IN` clause